# Why is the output not printing when using print(iterable)?

Tags: python, python-2.7

I am not getting why  output is not printed for case 1 and in second case after using `list` it's working.

Case one:

```
s='india'

print(reversed(s))
```

Output

```
<reversed object at 0x...>
```

Case two:

```
s='india'

print(list(reversed(s)))
```

Output

```
['a', 'i', 'd', 'n', 'i']
```

Comment: The output *is* printed in case 1. The output is an iterator.

Comment: Have you tried printing `list(s)` to see what that produces?

Comment: See the python docs at for `reversed` at https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html?highlight=reversed#reversed

Comment: @jonrsharpe i am a beginner, can you please explain why i can't see the result as  ['a', 'i', 'd', 'n', 'i']

Comment: You *can* see the result. Both of your cases print something. The result of the first case is an iterator, [as documented](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#reversed). You don't see the result as `['a', 'i', 'd', 'n', 'i']` because *that's not the result* - you have to consume the iterator to see its content, as `list(...)` does.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From the Python documentation:

[**reversed(seq)**](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html?highlight=reversed#reversed)

> Return a reverse iterator. seq must be an object which has a
>   `__reversed__()` method or supports the sequence protocol (the
>   `__len__()` method and the `__getitem__()` method with integer
>   arguments starting at 0).

[**list([iterable])**](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#list)

> The constructor builds a list whose items are the same and in the same
>   order as iterable’s items. iterable may be either a sequence, a
>   container that supports iteration, or an iterator object. If iterable
>   is already a list, a copy is made and returned, similar to
>   iterable[:]. For example, `list('abc')` returns `['a', 'b', 'c']` and
>   `list( (1, 2, 3) )` returns `[1, 2, 3]`. If no argument is given, the
>   constructor creates a new empty list, `[]`.

So:

`reversed(string)` will return an iterator that travels backwards through the string. `list(iterator)` turns that iterator into a list. `list(string)` will split a string up into its constituent characters.

Thus

`list('india')` returns `['i', 'n', 'd', 'i', 'a']`

`reversed('india')` returns `<reversed object at 0x1090b48d0>`, which is an iterator

you can convert the iterator into a list using the `list` operator:

`list(reversed('india'))` returning  `['a', 'i', 'd', 'n', 'i']`

or you could iterate through it:

```
for n in reversed('india'):
   print(n)
```

which prints out

```
a
i
d
n
i
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want the reversed string, try the following:

```
string = ''.join(reversed(s))
```

This is because reversed outputs an iterator, which doesn't hold values, but rather computes them on the fly. The ''.join part consumes the generator and makes a string.

See [here](https://wiki.python.org/moin/Generators) for more information on generators/iterators.